# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

```
<form id="registerForm" method="post" role="form" class="admin-form" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.AffiliateId" class="control-label"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col form-group">
            @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Query["AffiliateId"]))
            {
                <input asp-for="Input.AffiliateId" class="form-control" />
            }
            else
            {
                <input asp-for="Input.AffiliateId" class="form-control" value="@Request.Query["AffiliateId"]" disabled />
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col form-group">
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.AffiliateId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a field which is optional - `AffiliatedId`. If it's passed via the query string, it pre-populates a textbox and disables it. If it's not passed via a query string, the textbox is blank and allows a user to manually input or can remain blank.

This form is posted through this method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
```

When a value is supplied through a query string `Model` always has `AffiliateId` as blank. Works fine if user manually enters value on the form... stuck on this for hours!

Looked at similar issues on the web and none of them have helped me.

Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Changed the `AffiliateId` field from `disabled` to `readonly` and styled it like a disabled field. Inputs sets to disabled are not posted.